# Are these mushrooms poisonous and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: identification, fungus, mushrooms

There is a cluster of these in a shady part of the garden. I'm wondering if they're poisonous or how I can remove them.

I'm in Ireland if that helps.

[image: mushroom]
[image: mushroom]

Comment: Are they more bown (first photo) or with a lavender tinge (second photo)?

Comment: Would you please carefully lift / pull one and show me the bottom of the stem?

Comment: And how big are they? Height, diameter... It's a bit hard to tell from the photos.

Answer (score 6):

It's a member of the order [Agaricales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricales). Which contains many edible mushrooms such as the white mushrooms you buy in the store as well as very poisonous mushrooms such as the [European destroying angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_virosa).

Agaricales apart from chanterelles are often hard to identify and easy to confuse.

Touching a poisonous mushroom is not dangerous. However when dealing with any mushroom you are unsure of, make sure you wash hands thoroughly after touching it to avoid getting any traces in your mouth.

As to getting rid of the actual mycelium, that might not be possible or even desirable. Fungi help break down organic matter and make it available for plants. You can simply pull and toss the fruit bodies if they bother you.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure which varieties of mushroom they are, but even if they are poisonous, that's only the case if you decide to throw them in a casserole or fry 'em up for breakast, so just don't eat them. The mushrooms are just the fruiting bodies of underground mycelium, so getting rid of them for once and all isn't possible, but they will disappear on their own shortly. However, if you don't like the look of them, twist them off and dispose of them. It seems to be a very good year for toadstools and mushrooms, they're unusually abundant here in west London too...